# Jersey MVC web.xml configuration

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jersey

When I am trying to configure the web.xml file for Jersey MVC I am unable to get the result.
my web.xml file

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.res.app.Test</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

maven dependencies for jersey mvc:

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have a requirement that the html page content updated dynamically(text format and variables will vary) for every link. so i choose jersey mvc, As of now my project is maven build i am using jersey archtypes. Above is my web.xml file but while im trying to configure the mvc i am getting 404 error. please help me out, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider expanding your question to include the desired result, and how your current behavior deviates from the expected behavior.

Comment: @MichaelC. my question is updated. can u help me out

Comment: Take a look at [the docs](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/mvc.html) and checkout some of the linked examples.

Comment: You are mixing Jersey v1 and Jersey v2. This will probably lead to problems.